ebpf-tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_execve,has error:invalid variable-offset indirect access to stack R1 var_off=(0x0; 0x7f) size=9 (106 line(s)
the bpf code:
//go:build ignore
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";

struct execve {
    __u64 unused;
    __u32 nr;
    const char *filename;
    const char *const *argv;
    const char *const *envp;
};

SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_execve")
int sys_enter_execve(struct execve *ctx) {
    unsigned int ret;
    unsigned int args_size = 0;
    char argp[128] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        const char *arg = NULL;
        bpf_probe_read_user(&arg, sizeof(arg), &ctx->argv[i]);
        if (!arg)
            return 0;
        if (args_size >= 128)
            return 0;
        ret = bpf_probe_read_user_str(&argp[args_size], sizeof(arg)+1, arg);
        if (ret > sizeof(arg)+1)
            return 0;
        args_size += ret;
        bpf_printk("arg%d: %s ", i, arg);
    }
    bpf_printk("argp: %s\n", argp);
    return 0;
}```

the golang code:
```package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/cilium/ebpf/link"
    "github.com/cilium/ebpf/rlimit"
)

func main() {

    if err := rlimit.RemoveMemlock(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var objs counterObjects
    if err := loadCounterObjects(&objs, nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("loading objects: %v", err)
    }
    defer objs.Close()

    tpExecve, err := link.Tracepoint("syscalls", "sys_enter_execve", objs.SysEnterExecve, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer tpExecve.Close()

    log.Printf("waiting for signals")

    ticker := time.NewTicker(2 * time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    for range ticker.C {
        log.Printf("tick \n")
    }
}

and there is the error:
$ sudo ./cilium-go
2024/04/09 14:43:31 loading objects: field SysEnterExecve: program sys_enter_execve: load program: permission denied: invalid variable-offset indirect access to stack R1 var_off=(0x0; 0x7f) size=9 (106 line(s) omitted)
As you can see, I want to capture the arguments of the argv list in the function and store them in a one-dimensional array, but I've failed. I don't know how to fix this error or how to implement this feature. I hope someone here can help me out.

Could you please add var verr *ebpf.VerifierError; if (errors.As(err, &verr) { fmt.Printf("%+v", verr) } to the error checking of loadCounterObjects. That should output the full verifier log. And then add that full log to the question, that will help figure out what is going on easier.

Thank you very much. Your suggestion has been very useful to me. I have successfully identified the problem through your code. Thank you for your help.

@lxt You can post an answer to your own question, to help others who may be facing the same issue.

I found that this line of code char argp [128]={0}; In the middle, its size was set too small, which caused this error. Setting 128 to a number of 480 or larger can solve the problem

A little technical information goes a long way.
